# Когда срабатывает неявно commit в открытой транзакции?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3, transaction

Простая тестовая таблица с 4-мя пустыми строками:

```
CREATE TABLE [test](
  [id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT FAIL AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
  [col] TEXT);
```

Пытаюсь точно понять, что происходит в python SQLite с их `autocommit` и без него. Прошу поправить размышления и ответить на вопросы.

**пример 1**

```
con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
con.execute("UPDATE test SET col = ? WHERE id = 1", ['1'])
con.execute("UPDATE test SET col = ? WHERE id = 2", ['2'])
con.close()
```

Не срабатывает. Видимо закрытие базы данных не подразумевает `commit` (серьезно???) и нужен явный вызов `con.commit()` перед закрытием

**пример 2**

В [документации](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-controlling-transactions) в разделе "Using the connection as a context manager" сказано

> Connection objects can be used as context managers that automatically commit or rollback transactions. In the event of an exception, the transaction is rolled back; otherwise, the transaction is committed

пробуют вот такое:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
con.execute("UPDATE test SET col = ? WHERE id = 1", ['1'])
con.execute("UPDATE test SET col = ? WHERE id = 2", ['2'])
try:
   with con:
        con.execute("UPDATE test SET col = ? WHERE id = 3", ['3'])
        raise RuntimeError()
except:
   pass
con.execute("UPDATE test SET col = ? WHERE id = 4", ['4'])
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Срабатывает только последний запрос. Видимо `with con` продолжает неявную (smart) транзакцию, которая откатывается и открывается новая неявная для 4го запроса (ну и `con.commit()`, куда уж без него)

**Пример 3**

Выключаю неявную магию как показано в документации: "con.isolation_level = None"

```
con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
con.isolation_level = None
con.execute("UPDATE test SET col = ? WHERE id = 1", ['1'])
con.execute("UPDATE test SET col = ? WHERE id = 2", ['2'])
try:
    with con:
        con.execute("UPDATE test SET col = ? WHERE id = 3", ['3'])
        raise RuntimeError()
except:
   pass
con.execute("UPDATE test SET col = ? WHERE id = 4", ['4'])
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Срабатывают все 4 запроса. Как же так? Почему не сработал  "with con"?

Ожидал получить:

1. обычный одиночный `execute` сразу попадает в базу (автокомит для каждого запроса) без ручного вызова `con.commit()` для каждого запроса.
2. Если же несколько запросов должны быть в рамках транзакции, то ожидал что commit будет вызван в конце блока `with` (как он это делает в `smartcommit` режиме)
3. `con.close()` вызовет комит сам (просто следствие пункта 1)

то есть привычное (по другим языкам и адаптерам работы с базой данных) поведение "все запросы сразу попадают в базу, если не сказано иначе", оно же "ручное управление транзакциями"

Comment: добавьте пожалуйста в вопрос "__ожидаемое__ поведение"

Comment: @MaxU добавил ожидаемое поведение

Comment: @MaxU Проблема решилась наследником Connection, где переопределил __enter__ и __exit__ и передал как factory в connect. Заодно и вложенные транзакции стало уметь. Разраб так сосредоточился на смарт-транзакциях, что совсем забыл как должно быть без них.

Answer (score 2):

## пример 1

Да, как ни странно, по умолчанию (если не задавать явно `isolation_level`), при нормальном закрытии SQLite3 соединения, неявный вызов `commit;` **не происходит**. Об этом *вскользь* упомянули в [примере из документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html):

```
# Save (commit) the changes
conn.commit()

# We can also close the connection if we are done with it.
# -->  Just be sure any changes have been committed or they will be lost.  <---
conn.close()
```

## пример 2

если я правильно понял логику процесса, то после `raise RuntimeError()` - был неявный вызов `rollback;`, который откатил **все** что было до этого.

## пример 3

вы включили `autocommit`, поэтому все четыре `UPDATE` отработали. Блок `with con:` - можно рассматривать как неявное обертывание блока в следующую конструкцию:

```
try:
    BEGIN
       <your block of SQL commands>
    END;
    COMMIT;
except:
    ROLLBACK
```

Если `autocommit` уже включен, то данная "обертка" не поможет, т.к. после каждой команды будет выполнен неявный `commit;`

**NOTE:** режим `AUTOCOMMIT` отключает какой бы то ни было контроль транзакций, т.к. после каждого вызова `.execute()` будет неявный вызов `COMMIT`.

PS `AUTOCOMMIT` можно задать в качестве параметра `sqlite3.connect(..., isolation_level=None)`:

```
sqlite3.connect(r'C:\temp\test.sqlite3', isolation_level=None)
```

---

Из [официальной документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions):

> You can control which kind of `BEGIN` statements sqlite3 implicitly
>   executes via the isolation_level parameter to the connect() call, or
>   via the isolation_level property of connections.
>
> **If you specify no
>   isolation_level, a plain `BEGIN` is used**, which is equivalent to
>   specifying `DEFERRED`. Other possible values are `IMMEDIATE` and
>   `EXCLUSIVE`.
>
> ---

[Более полная документация о транзакциях и уровнях их изоляции:](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html)

> Any command that changes the database (basically, any SQL command
>   other than SELECT) will automatically start a transaction if one is
>   not already in effect.
>
> ...
>
> Transactions created using BEGIN...COMMIT do not nest. For nested
>   transactions, use the SAVEPOINT and RELEASE commands.

По-моему единственное серьезное отличие работы SQLite3 в плане работы с транзакциями заключается в отстутствии неявного "`COMMIT`" при закрытии соединения. Зная об этом можно просто всегда вызывать его (COMMIT) явно перед закрытием соединения.

PPS я не знаю чем вызвано данное отличие и тоже нахожу его непривычным.

Comment: Здравый смысл ожидает, что "with con" трактуется как в других языках db.BeginTransaction, а не игнорируется (о чем в доке не соизволили упомянуть), но в питоне решили сделать по своему (

Comment: @vitidev, именно так он и трактуется. Просто по умолчанию сразу после `sqlite3.connect()` неявно вызывается `db.BeginTransaction` и соответственно все последующие `db.BeginTransaction` - не имеют эффекта

Comment: "после sqlite3.connect() неявно вызывается db.BeginTransaction" - который по идее получает commit в конце execute, а значит к with con уже транзакции активной не должно быть. И откуда вы это взяли. После открытия connect до первого запроса con.in_tranasction всегда равно False в любой конфигурации

Comment: @vitidev, `.in_transaction - True if a transaction is active (there are uncommitted changes), False otherwise. Read-only attribute.` Обратите внимание на фразу: `there are uncommitted changes`

Comment: В общем  я понимаю данный подход как кривую (глупую) реализацию, где без smartcommit подход с "with con" банально "сломан",  а не "я где-то не так накодил". И проблема не в том, что стартует неявный " isolation_level, a plain BEGIN is used", а в том, что форсится commit даже в блоке with.

Comment: @vitidev, где, что форсится?? Если вы захотели использовать AUTOCOMMIT, то после каждого `execute()` будет неявный `COMMIT` вне зависимости от `with conn` блока

Comment: @vitidev, вы попросили объяснить почему транзакции так отрабатывают в SQLite3 - я объяснил... PS и где я говорил что вы что-то не так накодили?

Comment: Из документации это не следует. Документация весьма туманно говорит о том, что соединение может использоваться как context manager для транзакции, а именно делать комит если все  нормально. А для context managers это принято в конце блока with (что и подтверждается опытным путем) и никакого намека на то, что когда либо commit будет происходить не в конце with блока. Вы обьяснили "происходит вот так". Я "ясно. Правда это криво как то, но ясно"

Comment: @vitidev, может вам стоит задать вопрос о том как правильно реализовать "XYZ" (то что вы хотите сделать)? Мне кажется это будет более конструктивно чем ругать текущую реализацию - это сайт по тех. помощи, а не по психотерапии ;)

Comment: Нигде не говорили что я не так накодил. Это я подвел итог, что не "код не такой, а реализация такая". Придется написать вменяемую обертку с вменяемым поведением. И это не вопрос "как реализовать". Это вопрос "почему не происходит ожидаемое и документация не дает ответа."

Comment: @vitidev, вы можете дополнить вопрос тем, что вы ожидали получить? Подозреваю что никаких оберток писать не придется...